# Spring Mongo - Accessing repository interface methods from my custom repository implementation

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I am defining a Spring Mongo repository interface as follows:

```
public interface FooRepository
  extends MongoRepository<Foo, String>, FooRepositoryCustom {
  Foo findByMyField(String myField);
}
```

... and a custom interface like this:

```
public interface FooRepositoryCustom {
  Foo findByMyObject(MyObject obj);
}
```

In my custom repository implementation, I would like to define findByMyObject by calling the findByMyField method. Something like:

```
public class FooRepositoryImpl implements FooRepositoryCustom {
  public Foo findByMyObject(MyObject obj) {
    return new Foo(<repository>.findByMyField(obj.getId()));
  }
}
```

Any clue of how I could get a reference to that repository interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following ...

```
public class FooRepositoryImpl implements FooRepositoryCustom {
@Autowired
private FooRepository fooRepository;
public Foo findByMyObject(MyObject obj) {
    return new Foo(fooRepository.findByMyField(obj.getId()));
  }
}
```

You can also try

```
@Autowired
private MongoRepository<Foo, String> fooRepository;
```

Not sure if the generics will trip the autowire by type.